# Could you explain the little difference between my two hash?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest, oauth

I'm trying to implement a WCF OAuth restful Web API service.
Without knowing the code could you explain the little difference between my two hash:

> ```
>   dictionary["oauth_signature"]   "URirekG5i5MbWxoinc4bi4H8j1g%3D"    string
>   hash                            "URirekG5i5MbWxoinc4bi4H8j1g="      string
> ```

I use RESTClient (firefox addon) to test my WCF OAuth restful Web API service. [I followed this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/372422/Secure-WCF-RESTful-service-using-OAUTH).

It seems something is added to the end of dictionary["oauth_signature"] or something is missing in my generated hash. But what?

```
            if (dictionary["oauth_consumer_key"] != null)
            {
                // to get uri without oauth parameters
                string uri = context.UriTemplateMatch.RequestUri.ToString();
                string consumersecret = "suryabhai";
                OAuthBase oauth = new OAuthBase();
                string hash = oauth.GenerateSignature(
                    new Uri(uri),
                    dictionary["oauth_consumer_key"],
                    consumersecret,
                    null, // totken
                    null, //token secret
                    "GET",
                    dictionary["oauth_timestamp"],
                    dictionary["oauth_nonce"],
                    out normalizedUrl,
                    out normalizedRequestParameters
                    );
                Authenticated = dictionary["oauth_signature"] == hash;
            }
            return Authenticated;
```

Comment: The last character = is actually the same as %3D, but %3D is the URL encoded version (see http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: And which one is correct? With RESTClient I noticed all my hash finish with %3D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhere in your application, your hash got URL encoded. That means that the `=` sign, a special character in URLs, was encoded to `%3D`. If you decode it, they will match.

Comment: My application use the '='. RESTClient (firefox addon) encode the '=' to %3D. Should I stop to use RESTClient or should I fix this in my code. What if i use another REST client tool ?

Comment: I don't know how your REST client works or what you need it for. If you know it's encoded, you can as well [decode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.urldecode(v=vs.110).aspx) it before you compare.

Comment: The question is should I encode the one or decode the other? I don't know what are the rules and specificity of OAuth (if any).